# How to Streamline or Shrink this jQuery Code

Tags: jquery

I have this code to do a simple click to change .highlight color:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#colors").css("cursor","pointer");
$("#color1").css("background-color","#e3dc98");
$("#color1").click(function () {
  $(".highlight").css("background-color","#e3dc98");
    $(".highlight").css("color","#000000"); 
});
$("#color2").css("background-color","#588000");
$("#color2").css("color","#ffffff");    
$("#color2").click(function () {
    $(".highlight").css("background-color","#588000");
    $(".highlight").css("color","#ffffff"); 
});
$("#color3").css("background-color","#66ccff");
$("#color3").click(function () {
    $(".highlight").css("background-color","#66ccff");
    $(".highlight").css("color","#000000"); 
});
$("#color4").css("background-color","#ffcc00");
$("#color4").click(function () {
  $(".highlight").css("background-color","#ffcc00");
    $(".highlight").css("color","#000000"); 
});
});
</script>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion or example on how I can streamline this? ie... take 25 lines of code and make it 5 or 6?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Don't forget to check out [closure](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a couple things:

First, add a function that changes both the background-color and the color of a given selector.

```
function change_colors(selector, background_color, font_color) {
  $(selector).css({"background-color":background_color, "color":font_color})
}
```

And use it like this:

```
change_colors(".highlight", "#e3dc98", "#e3dc98");
```

Second, use the .css() syntax shown above to change multiple styling properties in one line.

These won't get you down to 5 or 6 lines, but it will shorten and clean up the code considerably.

Comment: ... additionally, chain your functions. `$('#color1').css().click()` format will also work, instead of repeating your selector.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This is what I was trying to get to.

Comment: so: $('#color1').click(change_colors(".highlight", "#e3dc98", "#e3dc98");)

Answer (score 0):

1. move some of the stuff you have in JS to a CSS file:

   ```
   #colors{cursor:pointer;}
   #color1{background-color:#e3dc98;}
   (et cetera)
   ```
2. Factor out the code from the data.  Create a map of IDs to the appropriate colours:

   ```
   var colors = {
       color1: {fore:'#000000', back:'#e3dc98'},
       color2:{fore:'#ffffff', back:'#588000'},
       (et cetera)
   };
   ```
3. Write a single JS function that does your setup for you:

   ```
   var fWireUpBlock = function(selector, foreColor, backColor){
       var newCSS = {color:foreColor, backgroundColor:backColor};
       $(selector).css(newCSS).click(function(ev){
           $('.highlight').css(newCSS );
       });
   };
   ```
4. Call the setup function in a loop during document-ready:

   ```
   $(function(){
       foreach(var c in colors){
           fWireUpBlock('#'+c, colors[c].fore, colors[c].back);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent response! This helped me to make things cleaner for sure.